# Understanding BizTalk Development

Tags: wcf, biztalk

Coming from a .net developer's perspective, I've been recently introduced to BizTalk. I was expecting something like a series of Service References, auto-mapping classes and workflows. I really wasn't expecting heavy XSD use and I was surprised by the orchestration maps.

I just don't understand why it isn't more like a bunch of enterprise features built on a foundation of WCF.

Can anyone help me understand the idea behind how BizTalk was designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research indicates that BizTalk has remained largely unchanged since 2004, and thus would not experience the kind of technological convergence seen in other areas of the Microsoft stack. The reason for this appears to be because of a painful migration from BizTalk 2002 to 2004 that no one wants to replicate. Reminiscent, to me, of the many versions of the Entity Framework.

In 2010-2011, there was a "BizTalk is dead" movement, with promises that a combination of WCF, Workflow Foundation, and AppFabric on Azure would be the replacement tools. There has been little talk of it at all since 2012 -- it looks like the two technologies both had their unique pros and cons, but never would the two compete.

BizTalk has the strength of out-of-the-box throttling and disk persistence and an assortment of adapters that aren't standardized elsewhere (enterprise-iness). It's as if its stance is to tame an unwieldy beast. It appears to suffer, still, from taking advantage of scalability options that have come about in the last 10 years. The other stack is more along the lines of what I initially expected but lacking in enterprise-iness.

I don't quite have my head wrapped around BizTalk being described as a publish/subscribe model versus... some other model. Need to look more into that.

In conclusion, I don't like either technology set, and I think they're both in need of work.

Thanks to all who read this question and those who answered it. I know subjective answers aren't a big thing on stack overflow.

Comment: "Proven" is one of the best words to describe BizTalk Server.  Yes, the core of the product is 11 years old by now but...well...so what?  It has worked, works now, and will continue to work for the foreseeable future.  WF was the only real opportunity to replace the core of BizTalk and for a while, parity seemed plausible but then, WF just stalled.  Please keep in mind, BizTalk Server and WCF are not really comparable.  It's like comparing a Windows Phone to the Polycom :)

Comment: @Johns-305 - I read that they wanted to replace the core of BizTalk Server with WF but they likened it to performing heart surgery. They must have concluded at some point not to mess with it.

When I say 'WCF', in addition to the wsdl standards I'm really thinking about svcutil.exe and the contracts it produces, abstracting away the XSDs. From a development perspective and not a guts/engine perspective, BizTalk is really stuck in 2004.

Answer (score 2):

BizTalk can work with WCF services, but doesn't need to for some simple scenarios.  It can also work in scenarios where custom non-WCF adapters are needed - it includes many useful ones out of the box, like for FTP, SFTP, File system access, POP3, Sharepoint, Azure ServiceBus, MSMQ, and MQSeries.  Custom adapters can be written for legacy systems and services that don't expose WCF endpoints.  There are many WCF adapters for cases where WCF is useful, and these adapters can be used and configured a bit more easily than drawing up a WCF Service from scratch.  BizTalk can also expose its services as WCF endpoints.

The real power of BizTalk is in its server architecture, which allows for high availability, durable messaging, suspending and resuming messages, advanced debugging options, and rapid development of artifacts (like maps and orchestrations).  It also provides for some powerful out of the box support for EDI, HL7, and WCF LoB integration work.

XML is at the heart and soul of the BizTalk messaging engine.  This is good because XML is standardized and powerful; it's bad because XML is unwieldy at times, especially when dealing with larger messages and BLOBs.

ReceivePorts get the data into BizTalk's messaging engine (using adapters and receive locations).  Send ports send the XML (or other) data out using the adapters mentioned above.

Maps use XSLT behind the scenes to transform the XML messages; it's possible to direct a map to use custom XSLT, or to use C#, VB, or JScript as well.  However, for most trivial mapping tasks, the visual mapping interface allows for rapid development and testing of mappings between different message types.  They can be called from receive ports, send ports, or orchestrations.

Orchestrations are more or less services that use the XLANGs language.  When designed properly, they can provide very powerful processing of business logic and application handling, all with the above mentioned architectural features that BizTalk provides (durable messaging, high availability).

Comment: I'm used to having my XML (or whatever standard) de/serialized directly from and to C# classes. And I'm not aware of XLANG being used for anything outside of orchestrations -- why are we stuck with a designer or use a specialty language?

Comment: BizTalk is going to save some of the cost of that de/serialization by just working directly with the XML.  It is still possible to serialize it to a .net class (and manipulate it in a .NET class library called from a pipeline or orchestration) but that shouldn't ordinarily be necessary in BizTalk.  The designer is kind of annoying at first, but it provides a quick visual look at the flow and logic.  If you have needs that are more complicated, you can call a .NET library from an expression shape

Answer (score 2):

I look at it from a different perspective.  BizTalk is more inline with Web/SOAP and cross-platform standards, Xml and now JSON, than WCF.  BizTalk also supports a lot more protocols than WCF.  BizTalk supports WCF, not the other way around.

That the WCF stack can build Contracts on and serialize/deserialize .Net classes is the custom approach.  Keep in mind, WCF is just hiding all the Xml/Xsd from you, it's still there and is the same as what BizTalk uses.

BizTalk was designed and shipped before WCF as a reliable, cross-platform, multi-protocol integration engine.  In terms of capabilities, the BizTalk stack as a whole is several orders of magnitude beyond WCF.  In practice, we spend a lot of time in a BizTalk app working around the limitations of WCF.*

*For clarity, I'm referring to the OOB binding elements mostly and their application to actual implementations.  WCF as a framework is perfectly serviceable.